# Error while running an open source project getnighthawk.dev by meshery

Tags: jekyll, bundle

I am trying to run that in my local
Have followed the steps:

```
git clone git@github.com:malaviya-parth/getnighthawk.git
```

```
cd getnighthawk
```

```
cd docs
```

Then as ruby was required, I installed it with default configurations
the Path of ruby/bin is also added in environment variables
Installed Jekyll and bundler

```
gem install jekyll bundler
```

installed files

```
bundle install
```

now during below command it is giving eror
The command is

```
make site
```

even tried this to run server

```
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

Error:
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkhJS.png)

given in Meshery Docs [here](https://github.com/meshery/meshery/tree/master/docs)

and getnighthawk docs [here](https://github.com/layer5io/getnighthawk/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING-gitflow.md)

I read a stackoverflow article related to this and tried

```
gem uninstall -aIx.
```

and again tried

```
bundle install
```

but the same error kept on coming